# Hard Drives are not showing up in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I recently built a computer that will act as a server. It contains 120 gb ssd (Boot Drive), a 1 tb drive pulled from a laptop, and a brand new 2 tb seagate drive.

I initially installed Windows and successfully partitioned all the drives, but was told Linux was better for servers, so I installed Ubuntu 20.04 over my Windows.

In Ubuntu, I’ve run the commands **lsblk** and **sudo fdisk-l** and they did not show up. I know they are plugged in and acknowledged because the bios correctly sees them (even unplugged and rebooted to make sure it wasn’t a ghost). Also, I checked the disk application and the ssd is the only thing to show up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Make sure the drive mode is set to AHCI.

Comment: Switched to AHCI and still did not appear.

Comment: By chance when you initially setup Windows you didn't setup the other drives as Dynamic Disks did you?

Comment: I just plugged them into my main computer and they are both acknowledged as basic drives in the windows disk management software

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I had the sata drives in sata ports that were not being picked up by Ubuntu. To any who has the same problem, RTM (read the manual) and always try different ports even if you are sure of yourself they work. I thought they worked because they worked in Windows, but I was wrong.